# Jenkins Shell behaving strange or am I missing some thing?

Tags: node.js, jenkins

In my jenkins build, when I check the node and npm versions, (node -v, npm -v), I get node v6.13.1 and npm 3.10.10.
Whereas, In my ubuntu bash, the same commands give me node v9.8.0 & npm 5.6.0.
How is it possible?  Or am I missing some thing?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, If you set slave label in job configuration, confirm the label represented slave machine is the same one as you mentioned "my unbuntu".

[image]

(FYI,  If you not set the "Label Expression", Job executes on Jenkins Server, it get node & npm version on the server)

Secondly, Check if you set "provide node" to slave

[image]